# For uploading a file to aws s3 bucket, how to calculate base64 encoded policy document

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to `AWS S3` bucket from `HTML` template, can anybody suggest to me how to calculate `base64` encoded policy document in `Python`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> 'VGV4dA==\n'.decode('base64')
"Text"
```

Python 2 documentation: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode
Python 3 documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: You probably mean `base64`. Maybe point to encode/decode documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Answer (score 1):

This is the Python code to encrypt the policy document to base64 encryption:

```
import base64

input = open("policy.txt", "rb")

policy = input.read()

policy_encoded = base64.b64encode(policy)

print("%s" % (policy_encoded))
```

create your own policy document as policy.txt

For more information regarding this, please visit:

http://s3upload.blogspot.in/